# how can I use Zabbix with Java-simon monitoring api (getting list attribute with zabbix)

Tags: java, monitoring, jmx, zabbix

I have used Java simon as an api for monitoring my specific values and time of change. then I connect to my program via JMX and get the SimonManagerMXBean (which is kind of an mbean) by using the code below:

```
ObjectName monitoringBeanName = new ObjectName("org.javasimon.jmx.manager:type=Manager");
SimonManagerMXBean simon = JMX.newMXBeanProxy(mbsc, monitoringBeanName, SimonManagerMXBean.class);
```

Now when I connect to the program via jconsole I see something like this:
[image: image of connecting via jconsole to my program]

Now as you see there is an attribute called CounterSamples which is a list of some composite objects. how can I get this list and use it in Zabbix?
For non-list attributes I use the below:

```
jmx:[<objectName>,<attributeName>]
```

And for composite attributes I use for example apple.weight as the attributeName. but what should I call if I need the list attribute CounterSamples?

Thanks in advance.

Thanks for @asaveljevs comment, it really helped me stop searching a not supported feature!
Otherwise there is an operation called "getCounterSample" (underlined with blue line in figure), which gives me each element of the list. But I searched and unfortunately there is no way to call an operation in zabbix!
I should wait for the other https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1142 implementation!!
in this way there is no other way to use the java-simon monitoring api! 
any one has any idea?

Comment: You might need to wait until https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1570 is implemented.